# Action Bar и иконки

Tags: android

Всем привет.

Кто знает как можно сделать так, чтобы например иконка "Поиск" в `ActionBar`  показывалась только тогда когда показывается конкретный фрагмента? Я конечно же понимаю что можно программно сделать, но может быть есть другой способ.

В меню есть:

```
<item
  android:id="@+id/action_search"
  android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
  android:orderInCategory="10"
  app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

`showAsAction` есть `ifRoom, Always,...` Может быть можно указать чтобы иконка показывалась тогда когда есть какой-нибудь фрагмент.

Comment: Нет, только программно.

Comment: @Suvitruf можно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сколько я знаю, можно добиться этого, если у фрагмента переопределить метод 
    onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){}

В котором вызвать метод 
    this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);

И дальше переопределить 
    onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)

у самого фрагмента, в котором создать нужное меню

Comment: Это, по-вашему, не программно? )))

Comment: @Suvitruf на столько же программно, как и просто создание меню. Я понял "программно" как взять экшнбар у активити, и добавить в него иконку поиска. Я же предложил правильный вариант, без костылей, "программность" которого сводится к копированию кода создания меню из активити.

Comment: @metalurgus в то время, когда автор просил полностью декларативное решение

Comment: @Suvitruf благодарю вас этот вариант мне подходит.